# Domino Rest service API to get Tentative status in Ateendee's calendar

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there any way to find the Tentative status of my meetings as an Attendee from the response of "GET /{db}/api/calendar/events"  or  "GET /{db}/api/calendar/events/meetingId" ?

Some documents say x-lotus-noticetype property with "P" indicates a tentative acceptance. But I am getting a status "A" instead, after tentative accept meeting in both 8.5.3 and 9.0.1 versions of domino.

Use case: To show my(Attendee's) tentatively accepted meetings in Yellow color , in my Web App's calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the JSON transparency property.  When an attendee *tentatively* accepts a meeting, the property will look like this:

```
  "transparency": "transparent"
```

On the other hand, when an attendee accepts a meeting, the property will look like this:

```
  "transparency": "opaque"
```

In other words, a transparent event doesn't block busy time; an opaque event *does* block busy time.  This terminology comes from [the iCalendar specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545).  See the TRANSP property in iCalendar.